# Hiding the console window from SDL

Tags: c++, macos, sdl

I am using SDL to attempt to make a minigame of sorts, but the console window always appears in the background. I know in Windows you can use "-mwindows", but I am on using OS X. I am also not using Xcode or another IDE. I am programming from TextWrangler and compiling through my terminal. Are there any extra linker options to hide the console window?

Comment: Sounds like you are compiling the wrong type of program.  In Windows, you would write native (using `WinMain()` instead of `main()`, and fiddle a compiler setting to say so).  I don't know the equivalent in Mac, but I bet your problem is that you have written a console application instead of a native Mac application.

Comment: @paddy ```main()``` works fine. "On Windows SDL provides WinMain(), which parses the command line and passes the arguments to your main function." (SDL docs)

Answer (score 0):

First, validate that your `main` has the right signature: `int main(int argc, char*argv[])`, then, make sure you `#include "SDL_Main.h"` and `#include "SDL.h"` from that file and then link with `libSDLmain`.